# Algorithm to calculate the number of combinations to form 100

Tags: c#, algorithm, scala

I am struck in a tricky situation where I need to calculate the number of combinations to form 100 based on different factors.

Those are

- Number of combinations
- Multiplication factor
- distance

Sample input 1: **(2-10-20)**

It means

- list the valid 2 way combination to form 100.
- the distance between the combination should be less than or equal to 20.
- And all of the resultant combination must be divisible by the given multiplication factor 10

Output will be

> [40,60]
>
> [50,50]
>
> [60,40]

here [30,70],[20,60] are invalid because the distance is above 20.

Sample Input 2: **[2-5-20]**

> [40,60]
>
> [45,55]
>
> [50,50]
>
> [55,45]
>
> [60,40]

I would really appreciate if you guided me to the right direction.

Cheers.

Comment: So as I understand it, the method sig to define your input would be: int[][] ReturnFactors(int countOfFactorsToAdd, int numFactorsAreMultiplesOf, int distanceFactorsMayBeFromEachother) ? Another question, if it's 3-10-20 does that mean that the 3 factors may be no more than 20 apart from eachother, or the greatest and smallest of the 3 factors may be no more than 20 apart?

Comment: @Jimmy, you are right abt the signature.. And 3-10-20 means distance between 3 factors must be no more than 20... [20-40-40],[30,30,20],[40,30,30] are valid. [10-40-50] & [10,10,80],[20,70,10] are invalid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope it's not a homework problem!

```
    def combinations(n: Int, step: Int, distance: Int, sum: Int = 100): List[List[Int]] =
      if (n == 1) 
        List(List(sum))
      else 
        for {
          first <- (step until sum by step).toList
          rest <- combinations(n - 1, step, distance, sum - first)
          if rest forall (x => (first - x).abs <= distance)
        } yield first :: rest
```

Comment: its not a homework.. i just simplified the business case i encountered... And your solution working fine as expected.... thank you very much..... :)

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, this will be a very slow solution, even for not too large values of step.  It seems you loop from 0 to sum (incrementing with Step).  This means that if your input params are 5-10-100, and you start with 10 as first value, that you will still investigate at least 2^4 possibilities (or even 10^4 possibilities if not taking the distance immediately into account).  And this is only for 5 values and a step of 10.  With more values or a smaller step the performance impact will be huge.  Look at my answer to have better min/max values rathen than just 0 and 100.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to divide 100 over 2 with a maximum distance of N, the lowest value in the combination is

> 100 / 2 - N / 2

If you need to divide 100 over 3 values with a maximum distance of N, this becomes more tricky.  The average of the 3 values will be 100/3, but if one of them is much lower than this average, than the other can only be slightly bigger than this average, meaning that the minimum value is not the average minus the maximum distance divided by two, but probably

> 100 / 3 - 2N / 3

In general with M values, this becomes

> 100 / M - (M-1)N / M

Which can be simplified to

> (100 - (M-1)N) / M

Similarly we can calculate the highest possible value:

> (100 + (M-1)N) / M

This gives you a range for first value of your combination.

To determine the range for the second value, you have to consider the following constraints:

- the distance with the first value (should not be higher than your maximum distance)
- can we still achieve the sum (100)

The first constraint is not a problem.  The second is.

Suppose that we divide 100 over 3 with a maximum distance of 30 using multiples of 10
As calculated before, the minimum value is:

> (100 - (3-1)30) / 3 --> 13 --> rounded to the next multiple of 10 --> 20

The maximum value is

> (100 + (3-1)30) / 3 --> 53 --> rounded to the previous multiple of 10 --> 50

So for the first value we should iterate over 20, 30, 40 and 50.

Suppose we choose 20.  This leaves 80 for the other 2 values.
Again we can distribute 80 over 2 values with a maximum distance of 30, this gives:

> Minimum: (80 - (2-1)30) / 2 --> 25 --> rounded --> 30
>
> Maximum: (80 + (2-1)30) / 2 --> 55 --> rounded --> 50

The second constraint is that we don't want a distance larger than 30 compared with our first value.  This gives a minimum of -10 and a maximum of 50.

Now take the intersection between both domains --> 30 to 50 and for the second value iterate over 30, 40, 50.

Then repeat this for the next value.

**EDIT:**
I added the algorithm in pseudo-code to make it clearer:

```
calculateRange (vector, remainingsum, nofremainingvalues, multiple, maxdistance)
{
if (remaingsum==0)
   {
   // at this moment the nofremainingvalues should be zero as well
   // found a solution
   print vector
   return;
   }

minvalueaccordingdistribution = (remainingsum-(nofremainingvalues-1)*maxdistance)/nofremaingvalues;
maxvalueaccordingdistribution = (remainingsum+(nofremainingvalues-1)*maxdistance)/nofremaingvalues;

minvalueaccordingdistance = max(values in vector) - maxdistance;
maxvalueaccordingdistance = min(values in vector) + maxdistance;

minvalue = min (minvalueaccordingdistribution, minvalueaccordingdistance);
maxvalue = max (minvalueaccordingdistribution, minvalueaccordingdistance);

for (value=minvalue;value<=maxvalue;value+=multiple)
   {
   calculaterange (vector + value, remainingsum - value, nofremainingvalues-1, multiple, maxdistance);
   }
}

main()
{
calculaterange (emptyvector, 100, 2, 20);
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for the idea... am investigating the approach...will update you soon...... :)

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use a brute force approach with few optimization? For example, say
N - Number of combinations
M - Multiples
D - Max possible Distance

So possible values in combinations can be M, 2M, 3M and so on. You need to generate this set and then start with first element from set and try to find out next two from choosing values from same set (provided that they should be less than D from first/second value).
So with i/p of 3-10-30 would

1. Create a set of 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 as a possible values
2. Start with 10, choice for second value has to be 20, 30, 40, 50 (D < 30)
3. Now choose second value from set of 20, 30, 40, 50 and try to get next value and so on

If you use a recursion then solution would become even simpler.

1. You have to find N values from a
   list of possible values within MIN &
   MAX index.
2. So try first value at
   MIN index (to MAX index). Say we
   have chosen value at X index.
3. For every first value, try to find
   out N-1 values from the list where MIN =
       X + 1 and MAX.

Worst performance will happen when M = 1 and N is sufficiently large.

Comment: Problem is that you can start with a first value that doesn't make sense and only realize this after you have added all the combinations.  E.g. for 3-10-30, starting with 10 wouldn't give a solution and you only realize this after you have added all the values, which will be deadly for larger values of N.

Comment: Patrick - I complete agree. This solution takes brute force approach and is not at all efficient although can be optimized. But on plus side, its quite simple to understand. Idea is to start from here and then make it better. Besides, in business situation, its quite possible that value of N would be constrained to say less than 5 and this solution will work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Is the distance between *all* the additive factors, or between *each* of them?  For example, with 3-10-20, is [20-40-60] a valid answer?  I'll assume the latter, but the solution below can be modified pretty trivially to work for the former.

Anyway, the way to go is to start with the most extreme answer (of one sort) that you can manage, and then walk the answers along until you get to the other most extreme.

Let's try to place numbers as low as possible except for the last one, which will be as high as possible (given that the others are low).  Let the common divisor be `d` and divide `100` by it, so we have `S = 100/d`.  This quantizes our problem nicely.  Now we have our constraint that spacing is at most `s`, except we will convert that to a number of quantized steps, `n = s/d`.  Now assume we have `M` samples, `i1...iM` and write the constraints:

```
i1 + i2 + i3 + ... + iM = S
0 <= i1 <= n
0 <= i2 <= n
. . .
0 <= iM <= n
i1 <= i2
i2 <= i3
. . .
i(M-1) <= iM
```

We can solve the first equation to get `iM` given the others.

Now, if we make everything as similar as possible:

```
i1 = i2 = ... = iM = I
M*I = S
I = S/M
```

Very good--we've got our starting point!  (If `I` is a fraction, make the first few `I` and the remainder `I+1`.)  Now we just try to walk each variable down in turn:

```
for (i1 = I-1 by -1 until criteria fails)
  sum needs to add to S-i1
  i2 >= i1
  i2 <= i1 +n
  solve the same problem for M-1 numbers adding to S-i1
  (while obeying the above constraint on i2)
```

Well, look here--we've got a recursive algorithm!  We just walk through and read off the answers.

Of course, we could walk `i1` up instead of down.  If you need to print off the answers, may as well do that.  If you just need to count them, note that counting up is symmetric, so just double the answer you get from counting down.  (You'll also have a correction factor if not all values started the same--if some were `I` and some were `I+1`, you need to take that into account, which I won't do here.)

---

Edit: If the range is what every value has to fit within, instead of all the

```
0 <= i1 <= n
```

conditions, you have

```
max(i1,i2,...,iM) - min(i1,i2,...,iM) <= n
```

But this gives the same recursive condition, except that we pass along the max and min of those items we've already selected to throw into the mix, instead of adding a constraint on `i2` (or whichever other variable's turn it is).

Comment: Hi Rex. [20-40-60]  is not a valid one... distance is between all or any item in a set, not necessarily subsequent items.. here "20-60 = 40" violates the rule...

Comment: Ah, okay.  Updated the answer accordingly.  It's still basically the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Input:
(2-10-20)

1. Divide the number by param 1

(50,50)

2 Check whether the difference rule allows this combination. If it hurts the rule, then STOP, if it allows, then add this and it's combinations to the result list

For example: abs(50-50)<20, so it is ok

3 Increase the the first value by param 2, decrease the second value by param 2

4. Go 2. point

Comment: "Increase the the first value by param 2, decrease the second value by param 2" what you exactly mean??

Comment: The first combination would be 50,50. The next one would be 50-10,50+10