# Create multiple combinations summing to 100

Tags: algorithm, vba

I would like to be able to create multiple combinations that sum to 100%, given a defined number of "buckets" with a defined 'difference factor'. In the below example, the difference is a factor of 20 to make it simple, but I will probably reduce it to 1 in the final solution.

For example, with 3 "buckets" A, B, C you could have:

```
A     100     80      80      60      60  ...   0
B     0       20      0       20      40  ...   0
C     0       0       20      20      0   ...   100
```

Each column is one combination (summing to 100) that I would like to store and do further calculations on.

This is a business problem and not homework.

Please help me come up with a solution. A brute force way would be to create a multi-dimension array for every possible combination, e.g. 100x100x100 and then go through each 1 million combination to see which ones sum to 100. However this looks like it will be way too inefficient.

Much appreciated. I hope I have explained clearly enough.

Comment: What do yo mean by sum to 100%, given that your first is well over 100. It's also not clear what you mea by difference factor, since it'snot a factor - do you mean the difference between adjacent buckets needs to be + or - the difference "factor"?

Comment: @Paul The columns add up to 100

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510586/algorithm-to-calculate-the-number-of-combinations-to-form-100.  Even the numbers are exactly the same (100, 20).  Are you sure this isn't homework or are you a colleague of the other question's poster?

Comment: @Harold, thanks. I was adding the rows :(

Comment: Yeah it was not homework. I did read the other solution, but it looked too different to my problem for me to understand (e.g. I don't worry about the distance between the combinations. The question related to asset allocations within a portfolio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is known as [**partitions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) rather than combinations, which is something different.

First off: the 'difference factor' just turns the problem from finding partitions of 100 to (in your example) finding partitions of 5 (then multiplying by 20).

Next up: If the number of buckets is constant, you can just do (pseudo code):

```
for i = 0 to n
  for j = 0 to n-i
    output (i, j, n-(i+j))
```

If the number of buckets is going to be dynamic, you'd have to be a bit cleverer, but this approach will basically work.

Comment: Thanks very much. This was helpful and less complex than I thought.

Comment: However, looking at it, the number of buckets is not constant. If we consider 5 buckets, the computation time is too high.  Back to the drawing board for me...

Comment: If we consider five buckets, the number of answers is also much higher! In fact, it should grow (in big O terms) exponentially in the number of buckets...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it would yield well to a bit of cacheing and dynamic programming.

```
fun partition (partitions_left, value):
  if partitions_left == 0
    return empty_list

  if value == 0:
    return list of list of partitions_left 0 elements

  return_value = empty_list
  for possible_value from value downto 1:
    remainder = value-possible_value
    children = partition(partitions_left-1, remainder)
    for child in children:
     append (cons of possible_value and child) to return_value

  return return_value
```

If you also make sure that you serve already-computed values from the cache, "all" you need to then do is to generate all possible permutations of all generated partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm wise you could make a list of all the numbers between 0 and 100 in steps of 20 in list A, then make a copy of list A to be list B.

Next, compare each of list A's values to list B seeing which values add up to 100 or fewer and store a record of these in list C. Next, do the same to list C again (checking all the values between 0 and 100 with a step of 20) to see which values add up to 100.