# Create all combinations of n*m values

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a data structure of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>` like this:

```
{
    { A, B }
    { 1, 2, 3 }
    { Z }
}
```

Where the outer array can contain *any number* of inner arrays. And the inner arrays can each independently contain *any number* of elements. And assume, for the sake of simplicity, that no array will be empty.

And I want to transform it to a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>` like this:

```
{ { A, 1, Z }, { A, 2, Z }, { A, 3, Z }, { B, 1, Z }, { B, 2, Z }, { B, 3, Z } }
```

Which contains every combination of the values from the original structure. So each element in each inner array maps by index to an element/array in the original outer array.

What is the simplest way to do that in C#?

Comment: I think this question will help you: [calculate the number of combinations to form 100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510586/algorithm-to-calculate-the-number-of-combinations-to-form-100)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use `CartesianProduct` method by Eric Lippert for this (taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) =>  
      from accseq in accumulator  
      from item in sequence  
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item}));                
}
```

Comment: I've not tested the solution - but the answer given is very elegant. Almost Prolog-esque in fact!

Comment: Is it possible to write a code in Java? Is there a link?

Comment: @JayPatel: here is a similar question and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4240323/102112) but in Java

Answer (score 2):

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> GetAllCombinations(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> a)
    {
        if (!a.Skip(1).Any())
        {
            return a.First().Select(x => new[] { x });
        }

        var tail = GetAllCombinations(a.Skip(1)).ToArray();
        return a.First().SelectMany(f => tail.Select(x => new[] { f }.Concat(x)));
    }
```