# How to get all combinations with different order in JS?

Tags: javascript

I've got an array with six items in it.

`['orange', 'strawberry', 'melon','apple','banana','coconut']`

I was able to get many combinations but the, unfortunately, my script isn't able to set e. g. the last item to the front so that I have really all combinations.

If you look at the end of the following output, you see that coconut is always at the end but it should also be at the first place, second place etc.

*(It is intended that there are no spaces between the items)*

```
orange
strawberry
orangestrawberry
melon
orangemelon
strawberrymelon
orangestrawberrymelon
apple
orangeapple
strawberryapple
orangestrawberryapple
melonapple
orangemelonapple
strawberrymelonapple
orangestrawberrymelonapple
banana
orangebanana
strawberrybanana
orangestrawberrybanana
melonbanana
orangemelonbanana
strawberrymelonbanana
orangestrawberrymelonbanana
applebanana
orangeapplebanana
strawberryapplebanana
orangestrawberryapplebanana
melonapplebanana
orangemelonapplebanana
strawberrymelonapplebanana
orangestrawberrymelonapplebanana
coconut
orangecoconut
strawberrycoconut
orangestrawberrycoconut
meloncoconut
orangemeloncoconut
strawberrymeloncoconut
orangestrawberrymeloncoconut
applecoconut
orangeapplecoconut
strawberryapplecoconut
orangestrawberryapplecoconut
melonapplecoconut
orangemelonapplecoconut
strawberrymelonapplecoconut
orangestrawberrymelonapplecoconut
bananacoconut
orangebananacoconut
strawberrybananacoconut
orangestrawberrybananacoconut
melonbananacoconut
orangemelonbananacoconut
strawberrymelonbananacoconut
orangestrawberrymelonbananacoconut
applebananacoconut
orangeapplebananacoconut
strawberryapplebananacoconut
orangestrawberryapplebananacoconut
melonapplebananacoconut
orangemelonapplebananacoconut
strawberrymelonapplebananacoconut
orangestrawberrymelonapplebananacoconut
```

Comment: please add what does not work.

Comment: Include your attempted code and a sample expected input/output

Comment: You might get some inspiration from [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510586/algorithm-to-calculate-the-number-of-combinations-to-form-100)

Comment: There are several questions with the same topic. Please search for "javascript array permutations"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look to this:

> ```
> a b
>
> a
> a b
> b
> b a
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> a b c
>
> a
> a b
> a b c
> a c
> a c b
>
> b
> b a
> b a c
> b c
> b c a
>
> c
> c a
> c a b
> c b
> c b a
> ```
>
> The above shows, that you can take every item and call the function again with the array without the used item. As result, you get an array with any combination.

```js
function getCombinations(array) {
    var i,
        result = [];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result.push(
            array[i],
            ...getCombinations(array.filter((_, j) => i !== j)).map(v => array[i] + v)
        );
    }
    return result;
}

var array = ['orange', 'strawberry', 'melon', 'apple', 'banana', 'coconut'];

console.log(getCombinations(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it will hit the Call Stack Range if you use more parameters but it will work for this example, thank you

Comment: I get the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` with this code... why is that? and how can I fix it ? posted my question here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553858/node-js-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

Comment: I just looked deeper and if my array has 10 or strings in it; then I get the maximum call stack error; but if it has 9 or less it works with no problem. Any idea how to fix that so it works with more strings in the array ?

Comment: @user12669401, maybe an iterative system would work with a stack instead of recursion.