# Node.js RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, stack-size

I am trying to generate all possible combination of a name from my array `productsDeduped` and then store the generated combination as `productTags` array. Here is my code:

```
//function to generate all possible combinations
function getCombinations(array) {
    var i,
        result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result.push(
            array[i],
            ...getCombinations(array.filter((_, j) => i !== j)).map(v => array[i] + " " + v)
        );
    }

    return result;
}

for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    var productNameStrings = getCombinations(productsDeduped[i].tags);

    productsDeduped[i].productTags = productNameStrings   
}
```

I get this error:

```
          result.push(
           ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getCombinations (/Users/farhadam/Silobee/Inventory/categories/execute.js:1006:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/farhadam/Silobee/Inventory/categories/execute.js:1016:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
```

Any idea how I can fix this; I assume its because of the high volume of request?

**EDIT:**
I just looked deeper and when I limit my `productNameStrings` array of strings to only 9 elements the code works no problem; but if it has 10 or more strings in the array it starts giving me this error! Still dont know how to fix it.

Comment: For a start, you can move your result array declaration out of the function because everytime you recurse into the function, you recreate it. Other way is to pass it to the function as a separate parameter.

Comment: I think the high volume is not the the problem, rather the call stack size that is how many recursive iterations are getting formed per input ( iguess thats 9 right now). A different problem solving approach called dynamic programming would help here, and by memoizing previous results you could decrease that stack size.

Comment: Im a little newbie here; how would I go about doing that? not sure how to code it as a separate parameter!? thanks!

Comment: I also moved the result variable out of the function but still getting the same error - though I do want the array to start empty everytime I go back in the loop as it would be for a new product

Comment: Every time your code calls a function, runtime pushes the current code state inside a stack, and pop it when the code returns. That's why you're getting the "call stack size exceeded" error: the stack is full for continuously pushing (`getCombinations()`) without popping (`return`). This is a common problem for recursive code. Can you show an example of what an input array and output array would be like?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Based on what I looked around it seems to be common. I restructured my data so I dont pass more than 9 so it is not a problem for me anymore. But I live the question open in case someone know how to fix it and be useful for someone else

Answer (score 1):

You can check here. Probably, you can't get out of a recursive loop.

> The problem with a recursive function that continues to call on itself
> is that it is impossible to move onto the next function within a
> chain, and you’ll eat up the entirety of your stack.

The best way to prevent this error is to double-check your recursive functions.

https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/javascript-error-handling-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

Another source:
https://www.educative.io/edpresso/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

Comment: Just ran into this while trying `npx expo install react-native-web@~0.18.10 @expo/webpack-config@^18.0.1` from a powershell in another directory that simply missed a package.json. So it ran into recursive loop trying to dig up that package.json.
"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at findUpProjectRoot (C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\...\utils\findUp.js:22:5)"